# jquery post get missing template in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, missing-template

in my jquery post I have code like this

```
function checkBill(trs_id, bill_id){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/check_bill",
      data: {bill_id: bill_id, transaction_id: trs_id},
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': '<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>'
      },
      dataType: 'script'
    });
  }
```

in my controller successfully get params for jquery post, but I get error missing template in my log?
I don't know why? I guess jquery post not need template

Comment: You need to return response as js from your controller

Comment: Are you sure you need your CSRF token in your jquery? It's alreay outputted in the meta code of your webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing template is basically a lack of **check_bill.js.erb** in your views folder

---

**Views & Ajax**

When your server receives a request (either HTTP or Ajax), it will process it by running the action & rendering the required view

Rails allows you to render HTML & JS views, which come in the form **`action_name.html.erb`** or **`action_name.js.erb`**. If you're sending a JS request, Rails therefore tries to render the .js.erb

---

**Returning JS Requests**

If you want to return JS requests, you'll need to use the code the other answers have stated ([`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)):

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def check_bill
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :nothing => true } 
    end
end
```

The difference is what you want to return to Ajax. I'll update my answer if you let us know what kind of response you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

you should give instructions to your controller action to respond with a js. Like this:

```
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js {render :text => 'ok'}
 end
```

otherwise it will try to reply with an html view